# Using array as parameter in service

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using array as input and output in a service. I am trying to extend the [existing tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(c%2B%2B)) for getting started. Below is the client code-

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "add_two_array_client");

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::ServiceClient client =
      n.serviceClient<beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts>("add_two_array");
  beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts srv;

  std::vector<double> a(3);
  std::vector<double> b(3);

  a.push_back(1.0);
  a.push_back(2.0);
  a.push_back(3.0);

  b.push_back(4.0);
  b.push_back(5.0);
  b.push_back(6.0);

  srv.request.a = a;
  srv.request.b = b;
  if (client.call(srv)) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      ROS_INFO("Sum: %f", (float)srv.response.sum[i]);
    }
  } else {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service add_two_array");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Following is the server code-

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h"

bool add(beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Request &req,
         beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Response &res) {
  res.sum.resize(3);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    res.sum[i] = req.a[i] + req.b[i];
    ROS_INFO("request: x=%f, y=%f", req.a.at(i), req.b[i]);
    ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%f]", res.sum[i]);
  }
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "add_two_array_server");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("add_two_array", add);
  ROS_INFO("Ready to add two ints.");
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

The `srv` file looks like following-

```
float64[] a
float64[] b
---
float64[] sum
```

While running, the input parameters shows 0 value. Below is the snippet from terminal-

```
[ INFO] [1465212136.691882517, 8990.505000000]: request: x=0.000000, y=0.000000
[ INFO] [1465212136.691913058, 8990.505000000]: sending back response: [0.000000]
```

How to use array as parameter in service?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236157/using-array-as-parameter-in-service/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-06-06**:
The existing tutorial can be found here http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(c%2B%2B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simple, but tricky error:
You are using the vector's fill constructor here:

```
  std::vector<double> a(3);
  std::vector<double> b(3);
```

a and b will already be filled with zeros like this:

```
a = [0 0 0]
b = [0 0 0]
```

with the command `push_back` you'll add another three values:

```
a = [0 0 0 1 2 3]
b = [0 0 0 4 5 6]
```

but this values won't be used in the calculation on your server, since your loop only iterates over the first three elements.

So either don't fill your vector in the beginning or don't use `push_back`

---

Originally posted by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) with karma: 305 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-06-06**:
Thanks a lot.. You really saved my time. I was debugging it but couldn't figure out the actual mistake.